# How to quantify correlation stability?

Tags: distributions, correlation, bootstrap

In many financial models we are interested in measuring the correlation between variables, returns etc. However, research shows that during crises times we observe "Correlation Breaks" where previously un-correlated variables become correlated.

What is the best way to quantify "stability of correlation" by examining the historic time series of the variables on which I am interested?

Would some kind of bootstrapping be a good way to start examining the sample distribution of the correlation? Is there any other method that I could apply?

Comment: Vaguely along the lines of your bootstrapping comment, you could consider partitioning the data set and looking at the cross correlation in each partition and see if there is a trend

Comment: Thanks Macro. Partitioning of the data is I assume a very specific variation of bootstrapping where although my data are partitioned in smaller samples, every sample consists of observations of consecutive days. Do you think that it would be good practice to pick up samples from non-consecutive days for financial data (where time plays a role) and examine the correlation?

Comment: A useful literature to start at is the financial contagion literature. Take a look at Forbes & Rigobon (2002) in the `Journal of Finance` and the papers that this research has spawned. (This is dedicated research into whether correlations change during crisis events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to compare constant conditional correlation with dynamic conditional correlation. In R, the [ccgarch](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ccgarch/index.html) package will be helpful. In Matlab, [Kevin Sheppard](http://www.kevinsheppard.com/wiki/UCSD_GARCH) has an implementation of DCC.

Comment: ProbablePattern thanks a lot! Would it be possible to elaborate a bit more on the concepts of Constant Conditional Correlation and DCC? My understanding is that for DCC we calculate the current correlation between variables as a function of their past correlations and their past volatilities by using similar methodology to GARCH models, am I correct? Also by CCC do you mean the commonly used correlation coefficient(ρ)?

Comment: DCC is a two step process. The first step is to run a GARCH model. This model can use any appropriate lag but usually a GARCH 1,1 model is sufficient. The second step is to fit the covariance matrix to the residuals of the GARCH model. The paper by Engle (2002) explains the mathematics and both Matlab and R packages automate the entire process. The CCC is the common correlation coefficient.

Comment: One way to use these is to use the CCC to construct a confidence interval and determine if the DCC ever violates either the high or low edge of the interval for any pair of variables. You could also use log likelihoods of both models for testing but I don't know enough of the math to explain the process. At the very least, if you decide to use either CCC or DCC, you should show that DCC is either warranted or not. If you have a few variables, I like the pair method that I described because it can easily be shown graphically.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with a simple 'rolling' analysis of the correlation to see how stable it is over time.  Here is an example in R:

```
#Get Data
require(quantmod)
getSymbols(c('SPY','EEM'))

#Rolling Correlation (30 days)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.RollingCorrelation(Cl(SPY), Cl(EEM), width=30)
```

[image: Corr]

Comment: Thanks Zach, that looks as a possible simple way to check evolution of Correlation over time. I assume to quantify, I would have to measure the St.Deviation of the observations and accept or reject the hypothesis of stable correlation. This is similar to the bootstrapping method that I was mentioning above. Do you think that taking non-consecutive samples would be acceptable for financial data? (e.g. returns on stocks?)

Comment: Sure,  you could use some kind of statistical test to quantify how far from the mean there series gets during 'events.'  In the case of EEM vs SPY it's pretty obvious from the graph... Your re-sampling method sounds like 'blocked-bootstrap' re-sampling, and I think there's R packages to implement that method on time series data.  It's certainly more appropriate than using regular bootstrap re-sampling, but your milage may vary.